# Создаю функционал быстрого входа на сайт

Tags: php, laravel, curl

На сайте есть форма для подачи объявление также поле для emaila и пароля.
В контроллере Laravel создаю новую запись user  .Но как можно из контролера реализовать вход на сайт пробовал через curl не логиниться. Как можно реализовать данную функцию ?

```
public static function signIn($email,$password){
      $laravelLoginUrl = 'https://хочуподкрышу.рф/public' . '/login';

 $fields = array(
    'email' => urlencode($email),
    'password' => urlencode($password)
);
$fields_string='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $laravelLoginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
     echo $result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#authenticating-users

```
$credentials = ['email' => '', 'password' => ''];
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  // Пользователь авторизован, можно производить действи
}
```

Comment: проверка выполняется но авторизация не проходит

Comment: @Николай как вы проверяете, что она не проходит?  если `Auth::attempt` сработал и вернул `true`, значит, пользователь авторизован. Получить данные авторизованного пользователя можно с помощью хелперов или фасада Auth

Comment: кнопка войти на сайте также весит

Comment: $credentials = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password];
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
  echo Auth::user()->id ;
  
}else{
    "bad";
}
      Странно id возвращает но при переходе на главную уже не авторизованн 
  }

Comment: как сохранить авторизацию

Comment: @Николай `Auth::attempt($credentials, true)`

Comment: не помогло $credentials, true)